# How to secure admission controller in EKS version 1.15

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, open-policy-agent

I am trying to configure OPA with eks cluster to authenticate and authorize client requests

I am refering to below docs
https://github.com/open-policy-agent/kube-mgmt/blob/master/docs/admission-control-secure.md

Is it possible to modify api server in eks 1.15 cluster

One of the step to authenticate client request is

API server must be provided with an admission control configuration file via the --admission-control-config-file flag during startup.

Comment: Admission control is already enabled in EKS version 1.15. I have added an admission controller with no issues.

Comment: Yes, you'll just need to deploy the validation admission controller configuration to the cluster.